# javascript dialog box with values to choose

Tags: javascript, dialog

I would like to show a dialog box, where the user is able to choose between 5 values.
The programm depends on the value, which is choosen...

 Which command should I use ???
 
This is what I already have

```
_item = prompt("please insert items name:", "");
_column = prompt("please insert column name ", ""); //here the user should choose
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: are there any reasons why you do not resort to the html `select` tag? for sophisticated ui elements, i'd recommend a suitable framework, eg. jqueryui, jqwidgets, kendoui, etc.

Comment: My html code showes a table and with javascript I programmed a little feauture. With a click on a button, you can add a new item in the table. But you have to choose the column. Only the table is allowed to be visible in the frontend. So I can't use forms. I added the code I already have.

Comment: the easiest way would be to augment the table columns with some `data-` attribute that contains the column-name. this kind of attribute is expressly designed to contain application-specific data and the specification guarantees that this data will not interfere with html semantics. btw, if you can, do yourself a favor and use jquery (plain fraemwork, no ui elements).

Comment: could you write a short sample code what it would look like?

Comment: have a look at [the demo](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.18631921.html).

Comment: [another demo](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.18631921-2.html) which sets the data-column attributes by means of js